# Quick way to get strided reverse of NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stride

I have an application where I need to reverse the elements along one axis of a NumPy array according to some stride. As an example, let's consider that I have the following array

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

I want to reverse this array along the first axis (`axis=0`) with a stride of 2. In other words, I want to quickly get the following array:

```
Out[4]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [7, 8],
       [5, 6]])
```

Is there a quick way to do this with a built-in NumPy routine?

Comment: "... reverse the elements *along one axis* ... according to *some stride*."  How general is the problem?  Is the example (reversing pairs along the first axis) the only case you are interested in?

Comment: It is actually much more general than I alluded to in my description. In most scenarios I need to be able to reverse only along the first axis of an n-dimensional array, but the stride is arbitrary (in this case I simplified it to only 2).

Answer (score 4):

Reshape to a 3d array; reverse one dimension; return to 2d:

```
In [51]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
In [52]: a
Out[52]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
In [53]: a.reshape(2,2,2)
Out[53]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
In [54]: a.reshape(2,2,2)[:,::-1,:]
Out[54]: 
array([[[3, 4],
        [1, 2]],

       [[7, 8],
        [5, 6]]])
In [55]: a.reshape(2,2,2)[:,::-1,:].reshape(4,2)
Out[55]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [7, 8],
       [5, 6]])
```